# Dll async function - how to report progress

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dll

We're creating a DLL asynchronous method that performs a lengthy operation. It will be invoked by an ASP.NET web application. We would like to report progress back to the client.

What are my options? Are there any good libraries for doing this?

Comment: Please, have a look at `IProgress<T>` interface (`Progress<T>` class); https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: You might find this useful: [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: The client would have to make ajax calls on a timer to a progress URL. 
The easiest way would be to just store the current progress in a property and then query that property every time the client asks for the progress update.
An alternative would be using `SignalR` to open a WebSocket.

Comment: What's a "DLL method"?